# iPhone application developed in Xcode 5, not showing icon and launch image while running on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5

I have developed an iPhone app, it is not universal. Now when i run it on any iPhone it's launching with splash screen and icon image is getting showed on device but-

when I run same app on iPad neither it is showing the launch images/Splash screen nor it's icon image is visible on device.

I am using Xcode 5, Deployment target is 6.0, and app is not universal.

Please have a look of images what i did yet.

[image]

[image]

what is the correct process in Xcode 5 to set icon images and launch images of any iPhone app, should i set it for iPad somewhere?

Is it because of resolution of images (Icon/Launch) for Retina and Non-Retina Display?

Comment: Did you run on iPad with ios version 6?

Comment: No, i am trying it on iPad with iOS version 7.0.

Comment: Can you update your question with icon and splash `images size` with `image name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In X-Code 5 image assets is the folder to manage the images including icon images and launch images but in my case to manage it i just check the resolution of every icon image and launch image, some of the images having correct suitable size for retina display but not having proper resolution so i corrected it.

Resolution Non-Retina: 72 
Resolution Retina display: 376

In image assets > icon folder > it worked for me when i put images with correct resolution and size i.e.-

Xcode 5 is smart enough to check the resolution so be sure about the resolution of images, I Think.

[image]

When i tried to add correct images in image assets > launch image, it didn't work yet so For launch image i used the old pattern to handle Launching image like-

[image]

It worked in my case, Hope It will help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need tick the required device and need to add `App Icons` and `Splash Screens` using image assets like.

[image]

Here are the sizes required for according to devices.

[image]

**Please review:** 
Remove app from simulator (Reset simulator), clean project. 
then check app icons and images in assets according to `iOS` targets and check if warning coming. then build and run the app And if stay remains [please review](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/AddingImageSets/AddingImageSets.html)

Comment: thanks for replying i tried it but not worked, +1 for details.

Comment: means you can find the icon and splash assets and you add the images but it's not showing right ?