# Launch image for iOS 7 iPhone

Tags: ios

all!
I have a problem. I've created launch images for my app. I added them through assets catalog.
Ipad ios 6 and 7 works, but iphone works only for ios 6. Ios 7 on iphone shows only black screen (for all: 3, 3 retina and 4 inch), and then app starts, but launch image don't shows.

Comment: Refer following doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html. I suspect, you are missing required resolution images.

Comment: Are there any warnings when you build? Did you add launch images for all resolutions? Did you try to close and reopen Xcode?

Comment: Yes. I tried to reinsert images, reboot mac, restart xcode. Is there any differences between launch images for ios 6 and 7 for iphone? I use one image for both ios 6 and 7 (640x960 (retina) and 640x1136 (4inch retina)), they work for ios 6, but not for ios 7

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701584/iphone-application-developed-in-x-code-5-not-showing-icon-and-launch-image-whil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, iOS6 and iOS7 require you to insert separate launch images for each… Actually, technically, the 2x iOS7 and 2x iOS6 iPhone launch images can be identical, and the R4 iOS7 and R4 iOS7 launch images can likewise be identical, but they are associated separately in the images.xcassets folder based on version.

To guarantee you have launch images associated with each version, go to Targets > General then go to "Launch Images":

[image]

Then select all of your supported devices in the right-hand menu under the 3rd tab (in this screenshot from my particular app, only portrait interface is available for iPhone, but if your app also supports landscape, landscape should show up here too).  To find out the "expected size" of each launch image, select its placeholder then scroll down to look for the "expected size" also in the right-hand menu.  And finally drag the appropriate images into the appropriate placeholder slots to make sure your app has launch images suitable for each device/interface.

[image]

Comment: This is how i made it! I set images both for ios 6 and 7 (but images are idential).

Comment: Oh, I see…  That's strange...  Hopefully Nico's answer of doing things the old school way will work for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem few days ago and i posted my Answer in this question-

[iPhone application developed in X-code 5, not showing icon and launch image while running on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701584/iphone-application-developed-in-x-code-5-not-showing-icon-and-launch-image-whil)

Hope it help you.